# Proof of distribution function lemma

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions

I have the following lemma from lecture notes

> Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a set and let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$ be a probability space with $\Omega \Cap \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \subseteq \mathcal{A}$. Then it holds that the function $\mathbb{R} \ni x \mapsto P\big((-\infty, x] \cap \Omega \big) \in [0, 1]$ is a distribution function.
>
> The proof of Lemma 0.3.10 is elementary and left to the reader.

While I indeed can easily proof the first two properties of a distribution function, I am not sure how to proof that $\lim_{y \to x+} F(y)$ and $\lim_{y \to x-} F(y)$ exist and that $\lim_{y \to x+} F(y) = F(x)$? Can somebody help me with that?

**Following the hint**

1. Prove $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb R$ defined by $x\mapsto x$ is measurable, i.e. $$\forall A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}): X^{-1}(A) \in \mathcal{A}.$$ This is true because in our case for all $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ we have $X^{-1}(A) = \Omega \cap A\in \mathcal{A}$ since $\{\Omega \cap A: A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\} \subseteq \mathcal{A}$.
2. The CDF of X is the function $F_X: \mathbb{R} \to [0,1]$ with the property that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ it holds that $F_X(x) = P(X \leq x)$, which in our case is \begin{align}
   F_X(a) &= P(X \leq x) \\ 
   &= P(\{x \in \Omega: X(x) \leq a\}) \\
   &= P(\{x \in \Omega: x \leq a\}) \\
   \end{align}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

Define $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb R$ by $x\mapsto x$ and prove that it is measurable. So it is a random variable.

What is its CDF?

Comment: Thank you. I tried following your hint (see question), but I am not quite there yet.

Comment: Your edit is correct. Let's denote the function described in your question by $G$. The CDF of the random variable $X$ coincides with this functions: $G=F_X$. From this you are allowed to conclude that $G$ *is* a CDF, wich was to be shown. You are ready now.

Comment: In my former comment I said that your edit is correct. But I overlooked something. For $B\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ we have $X^{-1}(B)=\Omega\cap B\in\mathcal A$ since $\{\Omega\cap B\mid B\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R)\}\subseteq\mathcal A$. This allows the conclusion that $X$ is measurable. You split up is Borelsets in $\mathcal A$ and Borelsets that are not in $\mathcal A$. The is not the correct route.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected the mistake I made. But I have trouble seeing why $G$ and $F_X$ coincide. Does that mean that $P(X \leq x)$ and $P((-\infty, x] \cap \Omega)$ are the same?

Comment: Yes, they are the same. $F_{X}(x)=P\left\{ X\leq x\right\} =P\left\{ \omega\in\Omega\mid X\left(\omega\right)\leq x\right\} =P\left\{ \omega\in\Omega\mid\omega\leq x\right\} =P((-\infty,x]\cap\Omega)$. You found that yourself, only with different names for variables ($a$ for $x$ and $x$ for $\omega$)

Comment: Great, thanks for all your help!